# Zero-sum games guarantee that, for all winners, there is a loser. // Zero-sum games guarantee that for all winners there is a loser

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, sentence

In various fields of academia, sentences with the following structure (arbitrary examples provided below) are common:

- Zero-sum games guarantee that, for all winners, there is a loser.
- Zero-sum games guarantee that for all winners there is a loser.

Another random example, to further illustrate what I mean:

- Newton said that, for every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction.
- Newton said that for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.

In general:

- " " that, " ", " ".

I've always wondered which of these is the "correct" (or "most-correct") way to structure a sentence of this sort. When saying the phrase aloud or just "mentally saying it", the punctuation adds brief "pauses" that partition the sentence in such a way that makes it sound much more pleasant and comprehensible. On the other hand, the second sentence structure has no pauses, and so it sounds relatively unclear and unpleasant. For this reason, I have always used the first structure.

So, to settle my mind on this, which of these is the "correct" or "most-correct" structure for this type of sentence?

Comment: Welcome. Have you looked up any guides on the use of commas? Most are optional and many guides I have seen tell us that they are over used. If the sentence can be understood without it then it may be best to leave it out.

Comment: Hi @Elliot. I have read a number of guides, and I realize that most comma use is optional. I guess I'm more-so seeking opinions on which sentence structure is "better", rather than "correct" (and to ensure that I haven't been doing something terribly wrong this entire time). I think that these sentences can be understood without them, but, in my opinion, having them improves readability and intelligibility.